# AWS Lambda 上で Laravel のクエリビルダを使いたい

Tags: php, laravel, aws-lambda, composer

Laravel で書かれたAPIサーバーの一部処理をジョブのように定期実行したいです

ソースをなるべく変更せずにかつジョブリソース管理しやすいように
AWS Lambda 上で Laravel のクエリビルダを動かせるか試しているのですが

[PHPで書かれたスクリプトをAWS Lambda上で定期実行する](https://qiita.com/yunano/items/25e41232a0cbd242f648)

こちらの記事を参考にした bootstrap を使って

```
.
├── bootstrap
├── lambda_handler.php
├── php.ini
├── composer.json
├── composer.lock
└── vendor/
```

という構成で Lambda をデプロイしたところ PHP 自体は動作できました

---

[素のPHPでEloquentを使う(illuminate/databaseパッケージの単体利用)](https://akamist.com/blog/archives/1041)
続いてこちらの記事を参考にして

```
{
    "require": {
        "illuminate/database": "*"
    }
}
```

という composer.json で compose install して vendor ディレクトリを作って

lambda_handler.php

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$db = new Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager;
echo get_class($db) . PHP_EOL;
?>
```

というテストコードとともにデプロイして実行したところ

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'PDO' not found in /var/task/vendor/illuminate/database/Capsule/Manager.php:49
```

というエラーが出ます

エラー内容をぐぐると複数の記事でどれも

```
yum install php-pdo
```

をしろとあるんですが Lambda 上なので当然何かをインストールしたりできず、
デプロイパッケージに含める必要があるのですがどうすればいいのでしょうか

[PHP Slim 環境構築(5) PDOとDBアクセス](https://qiita.com/dynamitecoolguy/items/325f66ce0370714c6335)
こちらに yum install なしでPHP上の設定だけで POD を使おうとしている記事があったので

composer.json に以下のように ext-pdo をというのを追加して
composer install から Lambda デプロイみたのですが特にエラーは変わりませんでした

```
{
    "require": {
        "illuminate/database": "*",
        "ext-pdo": "*"
    }
}
```

PHP のローカル環境で Laravel のクエリビルダを動かせる最低限のソースを
パッケージ化するにはどうすればいいか
お知恵をお貸しいただけるとありがたいです

Comment: 試せてないけど、この辺りが参考になるかな？https://dev.classmethod.jp/articles/lambda-custom-runtime-php-extension/

Comment: composer ではなく php.ini の方に追加すれば良かったのですね！　動きました！　ありがとうございます

Comment: 解決したのであればぜひ自己回答してください

Answer (score 0, accepted):

php.ini に

```
extension_dir=/opt/lib/php/7.3/modules
extension=json.so
extension=mbstring.so
extension=mysqlnd.so
extension=mysqli.so
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

と記述することで動作しました